# how to extract arabic text from table inside word file using python

Tags: python, pandas, ms-word

I wnat to create a python script that read from word file **.docx** that includes arabic text in table form  and convert it to dataframe.

Until now i am able to read the data but when i try to display it the system display like this :

> b'\xca\xda\xe3\xed\xe3 \xc3\xd3\xe3\xc7\xc1', b'2020/8/23', b'36016',
> b'']]
> 0  \ 0                    b'\xc7\xe1\xd3\xe1\xd8\xc7\xca'    1
> b''    2  b'\xdd\xd1\xda \xc7\xe1\xca\xcd\xe1\xed\xe1\xa...    3
> b''    4  b'\xdd\xd1\xda \xc7\xe1\xca\xcd\xe1\xed\xe1\xa...

## code:

```
import pandas as pd
import docx

document = docx.Document(path)
table = document.tables[0]
print(table)

data = []

for row_index, row in enumerate(table.rows): # Loop through rows
    data.append([]) # Add container list for each row.
    for col_index in range(13): # Loop through columns 
        cell_text= row.cells[col_index].paragraphs[0].text.encode('windows-1256')
        data[row_index].append(cell_text)
    print (data)


df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df.head())
```

Answer (score 1):

i must decode the text after it encoded like so:

```
 cell_text= row.cells[col_index].paragraphs[0].text.encode('utf-8')
        cell_decode_text = cell_text.decode('utf-8')
        data[row_index].append(cell_decode_text)
```

Comment: i can't accept my own answer now i must wait for 2 days that is what stackoverflow said